# Regular expressions in systemd service files?

Tags: systemd, regular-expression

I'd like to create a service that triggers on certain mounts. Right now I have

```
[Unit]
Description=Triggers after usb storage device is mounted
RequiresMountsFor=/media/sda1

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=media-sda1.mount
```

But I'd like something like `RequiresMountsFor=/media/sd[ab][1-9]+`, i.e. match `sda1, sda2, ...` as well as `sdb1, sdb2, ...`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The value of `RequiresMountsFor` takes a space-delimited list of absolute paths, but not an expression:

> `RequiresMountsFor=`
>
> Takes a space-separated list of absolute paths. Automatically adds dependencies of type `Requires=` and `After=` for all mount units required to access the specified path.
>
> Mount points marked with `noauto` are not mounted automatically through local-fs.target, but are still honored for the purposes of this option, i.e. they will be pulled in by this unit.

Reference: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html